# Syntax Highlighting when using special characters

Tags: rascal

I'm currently finishing up a mathematical DSL based on LaTeX code in Rascal. This means that I have a lot of special characters ({,},), for instance in the syntax shown below, the sum doesn't get highlighted unless I remove the \ and _{ from the syntax.

```
syntax Expression = left sum: '\\sum_{' Assignment a '}^{' Expression until '}' Expression e
```

I've noticed that keywords that contain either \ or { and } do not get highlighted. Is there a way to overcome this?

Edit: I accidentally used data instead of syntax in this example

Comment: did you try the answer and is it working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two solutions, one is based on changing the grammar, one is based on a post-parse tree traversal. Pick your poison :-)

The cause of the behavior is the default highlighting rules which heuristically detect what a "keyword" to be highlighted is by matching any literal with the regular expression `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*`. Next to these heuristic defaults, the highlighting is fully programmable via @category tags in the grammar *and* @category annotations in the parse tree.

If you change the grammar like so, you can influence highlighting via tags:

```
data Expression = left sum: SumKw Assignment a '}^{' Expression until '}' Expression e
data SymKw = @category="MetaKeyword" '\\sum_{';
```

Or, another grammar-based solution is to split the definition up (which is not a language preserving grammar refactoring since it adds possibility for spaces):

```
data Expression = left sum: "\\" 'sum' "_{" Assignment a '}^{' Expression until '}' Expression e
```

(The latter solution will trigger the heuristic for keywords again)

If you don't like to hack the grammar to accomodate highlighting, the other way is to add an annotation via a tree traversal, like so:

```
visit(yourTree) {
  case t:appl(prod(cilit("\\sum_{"),_,_),_) => t[@category="MetaKeyword"]
}
```

The code is somewhat hairy because you have to match on and replace a tree which can usually be ignored while thinking of your own language. It's the notion of the syntax rule generated for each (case-insensitive) literal and it's application to the individual characters it consists of. See `ParseTree.rsc` from the standard library for a detailed and formal definition of what parse trees look like under-the-hood.

To make the latter solution have effect, when you instantiate the IDE using the `registerLanguage` function from `util::IDE`, make sure to wrap the call to the parser with some function which executes this visit.

Comment: Wasn't there a post parse filter way without wrapping? I remember naming the function the same as the production?

Comment: yes, but that goes only for user-defined rules, and this one is generated.

Comment: Thanks Jurgen, the first option did the trick for now as I needed to do some user studies with the language during this week. I'm going to try to change it to the third option in the weekend, as I don't really like this approach. I've added the @category = "MetaKeyword" to lexical elements by the way, as it didn't work for syntax elements. This did force me to add the keywords to the abstract syntax as part of these statements as well. I do not like that, that's why I'm going to try option three this weekend.